# hide tab bar in splash screen in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile, swift5

I have implemented splash screen in iOS Application. it having 2-3 seconds duration but  the tabarcontroller from my home screen is shown in splash screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKjaY.png)

Comment: Can you please show some more code? how you have added tabbar and where?

Comment: splash already have no tabbar .. it depends on your code how you delay your splash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to add a separate window for your splash screen in AppDelegate. This makes it so you can keep the tab bar controller as your root view controller.

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let launchView = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()?.view ?? UIView()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
        launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        launchView.frame = window?.frame ?? .zero
        window?.addSubview(launchView)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            // splash screen shows for 5 seconds
            launchView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```